# Android: request internet permission programmaticaly

Tags: android

i've got a simple question. How does i request the permission INTERNET programmaticaly?

I done successfull granded CAMERA with a dialog from Android with:

```
private boolean hasInternetPermissions() {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private static final int INTERET_PERMISSION = 1337;

private void requestInternetPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                INTERET_PERMISSION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

At AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

But why is it not working with permission INTERNET?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `INTERNET` permission is not a dangerous permission. You don't need to request it at runtime, so it will not show in the request dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I've read the marked post. But i dont understand why android give that permission without userprompt.

Comment: Only dangerous permissions require a runtime request. For whatever reason, they decided that the `INTERNET` permission was not dangerous, so you don't need to request it as such.